# display template not displaying in choose refiners

Tags: search, refiner

I have created a display template using this link

https://www.eliostruyf.com/part-1-create-first-search-refiner-control-template/

I have uplodated the html in the master page catalog display template folder.It has also generated the js file. But i am not able to see the newly created display template in "Refinement confiruration for refinement" as shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it, problem was with adding the dsiplay template in Search Site collection rather than the site root site collection